# Broken garbage collection in Mesos

Tags: mesos, garbage

I hit a strange problem with potentially broken stale frameworks garbage collection on mesos slaves (**1.9.0-2.0.1.debian8**).

As per documentation stale frameworks should be automatically deleted if are not accessed for predefined time period, however while in slave log I could see slave is running out of storage, there are still framework folders dated more than week old.

I have following values set for garbage collection:

```
--disk_watch_interval="1mins"
--gc_delay="2days" 
--gc_disk_headroom="0.2"
```

```
$ date
Thu Nov  7 13:32:50 UTC 2019
$ tail -20 /srv/mesos/agent/logs/mesos-slave.INFO |grep 'Max allowed'
I1107 13:32:33.576203 27465 slave.cpp:7406] Current disk usage 71.83%. Max allowed age: 3.923527125292778hrs
$ ls -l --time=atime /srv/mesos/agent/slaves/bcb34071-9fd8-481a-8d0c-767ef0628216-S2/frameworks/ |grep Oct|tail -5
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 12:23 fbf26a3e-bb25-4f8f-b9fa-d089c46f7ebd-0004
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 12:23 fbf26a3e-bb25-4f8f-b9fa-d089c46f7ebd-0005
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 12:23 fbf26a3e-bb25-4f8f-b9fa-d089c46f7ebd-0007
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 12:23 fbf26a3e-bb25-4f8f-b9fa-d089c46f7ebd-0008
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 28 12:23 fbf26a3e-bb25-4f8f-b9fa-d089c46f7ebd-0009
```

Any idea for a reason that can happen and a way to force garbage collection (except adjusting gc_delay to zero and restarting mesos slave)?

Comment: I'm not sure if direcories are deleted. I think it only apply to tasks

Answer (score 0):

What frameworks are you using? Maybe you need to set `-gc_non_executor_container_sandboxes`

> [A new `--gc_non_executor_container_sandboxes` agent flag has been added to garbage collect the sandboxes of nested containers, which includes the tasks groups launched by the default executor. We recommend enabling the flag if you have frameworks that launch multiple task groups on the same default executor instance.](https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/9f1d38f491e8d9c02bebb094da87467bb70a8d27/docs/upgrades.md#1-7-x-gc-non-executor-container-sandboxes)